# Reading multi-dimensional Excel and importing to DB

Tags: java, mysql, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

I have the following Excel to insert records into DB using Apache POI and MySQL:

`Column A Column B  Column C  Column D Column E
                    V1       V2       V3
                    100      200      300
                    Axx      Bxx      Cxx
1   Description1    1        3        10
2   Description2    2        3        12
3   Description3    3        2        23
4   Description4    1       11        31
5   Description5    23      22        1`

I wanted this data to be imported to DB in three separate tables:

First table: The values of column C1, C2, C3 are inserted as rows in one table and subsequent columns (of D, E) just considering first three rows. I was able to do this with no issues and storing the column index as id field in that table.
Table 1 :

`3 V1 100 Axx
 4 V2 100 Bxx
 5 V3 300 Cxx`

Second table: I was also able to insert the values of rows of Columns A and B and rownum in this table as 
table 2:

`4 1  Description1
 5 2  Description2
 6 3  Description3 
 ...
 ...`

Third table: this is where I hit rock bottom, was not able to keep a map of cell (column C, row 4) and its value. Expected result was to have a map table with value, something like this:
Table 3 Expected:

`4 3 1 
 4 4 3
 4 5 10`

Have tried options of Map of ArrayLists, LinkedHashMap with Arraylist, but failed, in the same reading iteration, I'm not able to create a ArrayList of Arraylist, which is the desired output of table 3.

Please advise what is suitable approach using HashMap, ArrayList, or LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

Implementation approach

```
public int handleSheet(Sheet s){
...
...
//top level iterator for whole sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
int fcell=row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    for (int c = 0; c < fcell; c++) {
    //invoke second iteration via fn call

    if (cell.getColumnIndex() > 1) {
        insertFirstDim(sheet, cell.getColumnIndex());
    }

    if (row.getRowNum > 4){ 
    insertSecondDim(sheet, row.getRowNum());
    }

    insertData(row.getRowNum,cell.getColumnIndex());

    }   
}
....
....
return status;
}

private int insertFirstDim(Sheet s , int columnIndex) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        columndata = new ArrayList<>();
        columndata.add(columnIndex+"");
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex){// To match column index
        //do stuff here insert in DB
        }
    }
}


private int insertSecondDim(Sheet s , int rowNum) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        ArrayList<> columndata = new ArrayList<>();
        columndata.add(rowNum+"");
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        //do stuff here
        }
    }
}

private int insertData(int rowNum,int columnIndex) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        columndata = new ArrayList<>();
        columndata.add(columnIndex+"");
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        // using rownum and columnIndex stored earlier pick the select cell for values
         if (rowNum == row.getRowNum() && columnIndex == cellgetColumnIndex()){
         // pick cell values

          }
        }
    }
}
```